# Python Bottle <br /> not working?

Tags: python, html, css, bottle

I run into some kind of a strange issue, and I have really no idea of how to make things work :

I got a text-area where the user can type some text. Let's say he's typing :

> This is
>
> the user's
>
> text

When I store this in my DBB, and then retrieve it and display it on my template, I got something like this :

> This is \n the user's \n text

So I'm turning all the `\n` into `<br />` BUT when I display the text now, the `<br />` aren't working, and I got this displayed :

> This is `<br />` the user's `<br />` text

Here's some piece of code :

This is where I turn `\n` into `<br />` and send the string to the template

```
about = "<br />".join(about.split("\n"))
    return template('template/index.tpl', about=about)
```

And I'm using `{{}}` to display the string :

```
<p class="intro">{{about}}</p>
```

Did someone have any idea of how I could make this work ? ?

Comment: what output did you get

Comment: What did you mean ? On the final webpage once rendered ? This is <br /> the user's <br /> text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `{{!about}}` to avoid HTML escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do replace in the template itself. Following code will also works.

**{{'<br>'.join(about.split('\n'))|safe}}**

**safe**  is used for characters that should be escaped before being inserted in the result)